# Send notifications using REST api

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to use the http package to send notifications to topics through the flutter app using the docs as in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
{
  "message":{
    "topic" : "foo-bar",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

Since it requires Access Token which expires every hour. How do I manage it in flutter?

Comment: Is the `http` package required? Otherwise, you might have a look at the flutter packages. They do a lot of the heavy-lifting and handle stuff like refresh of the token: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/

Comment: How am I supposed to send request to REST API without http package? Yes, I am using the plugin but the plugin is capable to send notification to the specific user using his token. What I want is send notifications to the subscribers of the topic. There are admin sdk available for Node.js which easily manages the Oauth key but I found none for flutter.

Comment: another work around is to use legacy FCM API.

Comment: Yes I am using it currently but I want to migrate to the new API

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to get the OAuth code using [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package.

```
  Future<String?> getAccessToken() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging']);
    final c = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final a = await c!.authentication;
    return a.accessToken;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get key, `Project` > `Project Settings` > `Cloud Messaging` > `Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)`.

**Note:**

If you are newly integrating messaging into your app, use the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1). If you are an existing user of Cloud Messaging API (Legacy), consider migrating to the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1). [Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server?authuser=0&hl=en#choosing-a-server-option)

Here is the code sample you can integrate in your flutter app:

```
final endpoint = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

final header = {
    'Authorization': 'key=paste-firebase-cloud-messaging-server-token', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};


http.post(
    Uri.parse(endpoint),
    headers: header,
    body: jsonEncode({
      "to": "/topics/admin", // topic name
      "notification": {"body": "YOUR NOTIFICATION BODY TEXT", "title": "YOUR NOTIFICATION TITLE TEXT", "sound": "default"}
    })
);
```